# Are all works of Seo Kouji set in the same world but in different timelines?

Tags: kouji-seo

Are all of Seo Kouji's manga related to one another/set in the same world? For instance, his manga Fuuka is related to Suzuka as Fuuka is Suzuka's daughter. Are the other manga related as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suzuka(涼風), A Town Where You Live(君のいる町) and Fuuka(風夏) are placed same in Itabashi-ku Narimasu, Tokyo.

[From Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%A2%A8%E5%A4%8F):

> 物語の舞台は『涼風』『君のいる町』の舞台でもあり、作者が以前住んでいた東京都板橋区成増である

However, "A Town Where You Live" exists no direct relationship with others currently.